# F# - A type parameter is missing a constraint when 'k : comparison

Tags: generics, f#, dictionary, constraints

I have this line of code which gives the error stated in the subject line:

```
type trie<'k,'a> = TNode of ('a option * Map<'k,('k,'a) trie>)
```

I've tried inserting "when k : comparison" every possible way I can think of to no avail.  I can only find examples of this using one generic parameter and not two.

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
type trie<'k,'a when 'k : comparison> = TNode of ('a option * Map<'k,trie<'k,'a>>)
```

Comment: I was trying to add the when constraint right after the 'k, I can't believe I missed this possibility.  You always make this stuff look so easy kvb.  :)

Comment: @Beaker - Glad to help.  Since the constraint only affects `'k` it's tempting to try to put it there, but generic constraints always come after the entire generic parameter list - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx.